# Are body-language questions on topic for EL&U?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14155/what-does-it-mean-to-show-reversed-two-fingers) is about body language (i.e. a gesture) used in an English-speaking country. Is this on topic for the site?

Answer (score 4):

I think that:

> What does `XYZ gesture` mean?

is off-topic, while

> What is this gesture (`XYZ gesture`) called?

would be within the scope of this site.

Answer (score 3):

I would say not. Nor is American Sign Language, despite its connections to English.

Comment: Just a minor point: ASL is considered by linguists to be its own separate language; it has connections to English but so does Latin.  On the other hand, gestures *are* often considered to be a part of a language (for example, pointing at something and referring to it as "this").  So, I wouldn't personally link the fate of this question to ASL, which clearly doesn't belong.  However, even with that as my viewpoint, I find myself on the fence about whether a one-off gesture like the one in the question qualifies as a supporting part of language.

Comment: ASL is not strongly connected to English. It is, in fact, a descendant of Old French Sign Language and of Martha's Vineyard Sign Language.